# Actions SDK conv.hasScreen not working as expected

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I am building an action using DialogFlow and Firebase cloud functions. I have a simple check to either ask a question or close the conversation depending on user's device type.

```
 if (conv.hasScreen) {
      response += `Do you want to see a picture?`;
      conv.ask(response);
      return;
  }
  else{
    conv.close(response);
    return;
  }
```

I tested using Google Home mini, as expected, the conversation gracefully closed. But when I tested on a phone, the if check failed and the conversation was closed again. I was expecting the contestation to continue and assistant would ask me to show a picture but it did not happen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following to understand [Surface Capabilities](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities).

Are you using the following statement or not?

```
const hasScreen =
    conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT');
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the syntax is simply [`conv.screen`](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation.conversation-1.html#screen). As the property `hasScreen` does not exist, the conditional always returns undefined, which is a falsey value.